# CopyFromScreen method never finishes when performed by an Azure agent

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops

I am taking screenshot during UI Test execution by Azure Agent.

For some reason, this line never completes, there is no error, no exception it just waits on it indefinitely:

```
g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, new Size(recorderParams.SourceWidth, recorderParams.SourceHeight), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

This code is run in a separate thread:

```
   captureFrameThread = new Thread(TakeScreenshot)
            {
                IsBackground = false
            };
   captureFrameThread.Start();
```

and the full methods looks like this:

```
    public byte[] TakeScreenshot()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[recorderParams.SourceWidth * recorderParams.SourceHeight * 4];
        HooksSetup.AppendToFile("Taken screenshot 1");

        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(recorderParams.SourceWidth, recorderParams.SourceHeight))
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Low;
                g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
                // it gets stuck on a call below
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, new Size(recorderParams.SourceWidth, recorderParams.SourceHeight), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                g.Flush();
                var bits = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, recorderParams.SourceWidth, recorderParams.SourceHeight), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
               Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                bmp.UnlockBits(bits);
            }
        }            
        return buffer;
    }
```

On my local machine this code always works flawlessly.

Why is it so? What is my alternative?

Comment: Which [azure agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent) are you using?

Comment: Your code is probably running in an application that has no "screen": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870987/screen-capture-using-windows-service#comment27848757_18870987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason behind these problems was that agent didn't get enough time to login and `Graphics.CopyFromScreen` method was blocked. I had to defer taking screenshots and it all started working.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is related to the fact that your `CopyFromScreen` runs inside an agent without the same capabilities that you have in your desktop (log in, resolution, different browsers, Administration permissions, etc. ).

Microsoft says in his doc:

`When running automated tests in the CI/CD pipeline, you may need a special configuration in order to run UI tests such as Selenium, Appium or Coded UI tests.`

Considerations and configurations are explained in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-mode

If you need to troubleshot your test check this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-mode

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the [Azure DevOps labs](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/) here to execute UI tests as part of the pipelines.